# Proving surjective homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be an abelian group. Let $H=\{x^2 : x \in G\}$ and $K=\{x \in G: x^2=e\}$. Prove that $f(x)=x^2$ is a homomorphism of $G$ *onto* $H$.

---

So far I have $$\text{Take} \ \ a,b \in G. \ \text{Then} \ \ f(ab)=(ab)^2=abab=aabb=a^2b^2=f(a)f(b).$$

I don't know how to show that this map is surjective.

Comment: By definition of $H$? Note $H = f(G)$. (And the question has nothing to do with $K$?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to show it is surjective, you want to take an element of $h\in H$ and show there exists an element $g\in G$ with $f(g)=h$.  But if $h\in H$, then we know, by the definition of $H$, there exists a $g$ such that $g^{2}=h$, so we are done.  Does this make sense?